# Diodes in input protection circuits

Tags: protection, input, fet

[image: Over/Under voltage protection and regulation]

I'm studying this protection circuit that protects a microcontroller from inductive transients, switches, and other things in a small aircraft, which would be similar to a car/motorcycle/boat in that it has to deal with relays, contactors, the alternator, and other inductive things.

I understand the purpose of Q3/D5/R5 as the reverse polarity protection.  I understand the filtering caps (C8/C7/C5/C6) around the voltage regulator.  But I don't understand the purpose of D4, C9, and D2.  Thus my question:

1. What does D2 do?  Looks like a TVS diode, is that to short out the input when it's well over voltage?
2. What does C9 do?  It appears to me the R5 limits the current and biases Q3, but why the cap?  Looks like an RC circuit, but why would we need a filter here?
3. What does D4 do?  I can't think of a case where current would ever flow from the input pin of the regulator and I've never seen a diode like that next to a regulator.
4. What would be a typical part for Q3 and D2 if I desired input protection to +/-60V but typical input voltage of 14.5?  Looks like I have a bit of reading to do in regards to FET selection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D2 is a bipolar TVS. It's to protect against large positive or negative transients by shunting them out. There is no series impedance so it won't necessarily do well against high current or high energy transients.

C9 is probably not necessary. There is a lot of capacitance in Q3's gate and some in the zener. It might help if there was some possibility of the input voltage being **suddenly** reversed after being in the correct polarity, in which case the MOSFET could conduct  a
large negative current for maybe hundreds of microseconds.

D4 isolates the 7805 for some reason. Possibly to do with whatever Vbb is used for (backup battery charging?). It prevents a short on Vbb from suddenly reducing the input voltage to the regulator, though that's usually not a problem with only 5V. Also if a negative transient makes it through the MOSFET it protects the 7805. The electrolytic capacitors would probably be okay, assuming they're not tantalums.

---

You'd want to pick the MOSFET based on the **minimum** input voltage, which might be the voltage during cranking or something like that, and the maximum current and allowable voltage drop. If the input voltage can fall to (say) 7V then the MOSFET needs to be fully on at 7V. It also must be able to block the highest negative input voltage that might be applied. For that you'd look at the TVS specification at the maximum negative input current.

If you're not so concerned about low voltage drop, you can replace the MOSFET and the three associated parts with a 1N4007 which will withstand -1kV and is smaller, cheaper and likely more reliable.

TVS selection- you need to protect the MOSFET against breakdown when blocking and the 7805 against the 35V or so that it can deal with - so the voltage across it should not exceed those **when subjected to the maximum current that you are expected to protect against**. It also needs to not join the choir invisible itself, so maximum energy of the expected transient is a consideration. You also must ensure the TVS does not conduct with the maximum applied (non-transient) voltage (or it will quickly die).

Note that this circuit does not have a lot of bulk filtering (44uF is not much) so if the input voltage falls below the dropout the output voltages will go out of regulation rather quickly (milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment about Q3, D5, and C9.
C9 and R5 provide the path to ground for the GATE of Q3. C9 and R5 provide the RC timeconstant, so that the gate voltage rises gradually (and limits, or slows down the inrush current) from Drain to Source of Q3.
D5 (was selected as the max Vgs delta voltage) that turns on Q3 to provide max  Ids current; smallest Rdson.

Thank you.